# How to send multiple parameters in nervgh's Angular File Upload (.NET)?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angular-file-upload

I'd like to perform an action when all files are uploaded successfully. I'm using [nervgh's angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload). I have no idea how to do this!

In controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddMessageToTopic(OfferClientReponse response, int topicId, string messageText)
```

It corresponds with `response: $scope.data, topicId: $scope.topicMsgsToShow, messageText: $scope.dataForNewMessage.MsgText` in AngularJS.

I've tried:

```
var url = '/OfferClientData/AddMessageToTopic';

$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: url,
    headers: { response: $scope.data, topicId: $scope.topicMsgsToShow, messageText: $scope.dataForNewMessage.MsgText }
});
```

Also:
`formData: [ $scope.data, $scope.topicMsgsToShow, $scope.dataForNewMessage.MsgText ]`

Neither of them work.

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32059171/2181676

Comment: I don't think that answers my question, I must use nervgh's solution.